# Reading list from CSV and convert to float list

Tags: python, csv

I want to do some math on my data and stuck with it.
I am reading string lists from csv files and can plot them so far.
Now I am trying to convert the string lists to float lists as i want to do some math on the list items and create new lists and plot them.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("testlog.csv") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n')

time = [row.split(',')[0] for row in data]
gyro_x_lsb = [row.split(',')[1] for row in data]
gyro_y = [row.split(',')[2] for row in data]
gyro_z = [row.split(',')[3] for row in data]
accel_x = [row.split(',')[4] for row in data]
accel_y = [row.split(',')[5] for row in data]
accel_z = [row.split(',')[6] for row in data]
comp_x = [row.split(',')[7] for row in data]
comp_y = [row.split(',')[8] for row in data]
comp_z = [row.split(',')[9] for row in data]
temp = [row.split(',')[10] for row in data]

gyro_x_lsb = float(gyro_x_lsb)# make floats in a new list
gyro_x_dps = [gyro_x_lsb / (32768*2000) for gyro_x_dps_f in gyro_x_lsb]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.set_title("Gyro X AR [LSB]")
ax1.set_xlabel('Time[ms]')
ax1.set_ylabel('AR [LSB]')
ax1.plot(time,gyro_x_lsb, c='r', label='X')
leg = ax1.legend()

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.set_title("MPU9250_test_Accel")
ax2.set_xlabel('Time[ms]')
ax2.set_ylabel('Acceleration')
ax2.plot(time,accel_x, c='r', label='Accel_X')
leg = ax2.legend()

plt.show()
```

I am trying to calculate every item in "gyro_x_lsb"/32768*2000. But it will not work.
I have tried map also already.

Thanks in advance...
TMP36

BTW: I use Anaconda 3(2.5.0) with Python 3.5
I am new to Python and to this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will do a lot for you.

Like:

```
gyro_x_lsb_sum = sum(float(item) for item in gyro_x_lsb)
```

Here I am using [a generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) which is the same syntax as a list comprehension, but better performance in this case.

Hope it helps a bit.

*PS. Consider using the Python `csv` module to read CSV files.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints with the CSV module. This read my data now as tuple. This was also new to me, and I found a possibility to make some math on my data. Here is the code now that works for me, maybe not perfect, but i am happy for now.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("testlog.csv") as data:
    #reader = csv.reader(data) #read columns as strings
    reader = csv.reader(data, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) #read columns as numbers
    time, gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z, accel_x, accel_y, accel_z, comp_x, comp_y, comp_z, temp = zip(*reader)

#gyro_x_dps = gyro_x

def gyro_x_dps(gyro_x):
    return tuple( [e / 65536000 for e in gyro_x])

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.set_title("Gyro X AR [LSB]")
ax1.set_xlabel('Time[ms]')
ax1.set_ylabel('AR [LSB]')
ax1.plot(time,gyro_x, c='r', label='X')
leg = ax1.legend()

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.set_title("Gyro X AR [dps]")
ax2.set_xlabel('Time[ms]')
ax2.set_ylabel('AR [dps]')
ax2.plot(time,gyro_x_dps(gyro_x), c='r', label='X')
leg = ax2.legend()

plt.show()
```